# Arranging menu items according to their widths in html

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I would like to know the better way to arrange the list items for the below menu.
As If I mention the list items as Item1,tem2,Item3 and so on as the Item is a small word it occupies less space and all are looking fine in the width as shown below:

[image]
But if I take the name as "Features", Support","How it works?" then it is not arranging them properly as it shows me lot of space n between each list item.
So is there any better way to get rid of this such as expanded menu by it's width or something like that

[image]

This is my css for the menu:

```
.menu
{
    background-image: url('../images/header.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


ul.menu { 
    display:block;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    height:60px;
    text-align:right;
}

ul.menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:30px;
    margin-right:10px;

}      

ul.menu li:first-child {
    float:left;   
    margin-left:10px;
}

ul.menu li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 50%;
    color: #eee;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
```

This is my markup:

```
 <div class="menu">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href ="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#">Support</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#">How it work's</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Actually according to Derek answer If I changed my width to 100px then it shows me this way

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width:50px;` is your problem.

You can remove it and:

1. manually set each item OR
2. create a function to measure the width of it's contents and adjust accordingly OR
3. leave them with no defined width

   `<li style="width: 60px;"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>`

   `<li style="width: 130px;"><a href="#">How it work's</a></li>`

Comment: @Derek-Fist thanks for your reply and as based on your answer if I changed then it shows me that way as updated in my question.As it gives me lot of useless space in between each list item.

Comment: @Derek-At last found the right way which you suggested without mentioning width it worked well.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Next time you post a question, you might want to use jsfiddle.net which allows us to easily test answers and provide you with a more detailed and quality answer.

Comment: @Derek-Sure I will do that as most of them do not like it as the links won't appear for the next time and they ask to post the entire source code here.

Comment: You might want to specify each width individually. "How it works" will obviously need to be wider than "Blog". And I'm not sure why you have an apostrophe on "work's".

Comment: @Derek-Yes what you said is right that is why I have mentioned in the question that small letters dosent take much space rather than large words and just for the example I have mentioned "work's"